# "Unable to Load Servlet Class in specified module" shown while adding servlet to war file

Tags: java, servlets, application-server

I'm using sun java app server 8.0 PE, I have created webapplication and added some servlets and deployed successful. after some time I again, tried to add someother servlet as a webcomponent, while adding I got following error , what is problem exactly?

> "Unable to load servlet calss
>   specified in module,
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   junit/framework/Testcase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Just remove the libraries from the webapp or war file, and add servlet class now with library. this will add the servlet as web component successfully..

@Aito: thanks for your idea

Comment: I'm glad you could fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to add a library. Your application seems to reference to a class that is not loaded (or founded).

Comment: I added and deployed the same type of file as webcomponent earlier, but they added successfully.ofcourse I added libraries that time. Now again, I added library as well the class file, it shows the same error again